# passing model and parameter with RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, controller

I want to send a string and a model (object) to another action.

```
var hSM = new HotelSearchModel();
hSM.CityID = CityID;
hSM.StartAt = StartAt;
hSM.EndAt = EndAt;
hSM.AdultCount = AdultCount;
hSM.ChildCount = ChildCount;

return RedirectToAction("Search", new { culture = culture, hotelSearchModel = hSM });
```

When I use the `new` keyword it sends `null` object, although I set the objects `hSm` property.

This is my `Search` action :

```
public ActionResult Search(string culture, HotelSearchModel hotelSearchModel)
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't send data with a `RedirectAction`.
That's because you're doing a `301` redirection and that goes back to the client.

What you need to is save it in TempData:

```
var hSM = new HotelSearchModel();
hSM.CityID = CityID;
hSM.StartAt = StartAt;
hSM.EndAt = EndAt;
hSM.AdultCount = AdultCount;
hSM.ChildCount=ChildCount;
TempData["myObj"] = new { culture = culture,hotelSearchModel = hSM };

return RedirectToAction("Search");
```

After that you can retrieve again from the TempData:

```
public ActionResult Search(string culture, HotelSearchModel hotelSearchModel)
{
    var obj = TempData["myObj"];
    hotelSearchModel = obj.hotelSearchModel;
    culture = obj.culture;
}
```