# Passing Model from One Controller to Another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to pass a View Model from one controller to another controller. I used the below statement.

```
return RedirectToAction("FillNewSession", "Account", new { LoginResult = loginResult });
```

LoginResult is an object of the model "UserLoginProperties". FillNewSession controller is below.

```
    public ActionResult FillNewSession(UserLoginProperties LoginResult)
    {
        Session["UserID"] = LoginResult.UserID.ToString();
        Session["LoginID"] = LoginResult.LoginID;
        Session["UserFullName"] = LoginResult.UserFullName;
        Session["UserTypeID"] = LoginResult.UserTypeID;
        Session["UserRefNo"] = LoginResult.UserRefNo;
        Session["UserNRIC"] = LoginResult.UserNRIC;

        return Redirect("~/index.aspx");
    }
```

Problem is when "FillNewSession" controller is executed the passed parameter "LoginResult" is null.

Please Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing model and parameter with RedirectToAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468061/passing-model-and-parameter-with-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass an object through a redirect call you need to send all the properties of the object one by one, as illustrated below. You can't just pass the object as it is.

```
public class UserLoginProperties 
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string LoginID { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var prop = new UserLoginProperties(){ LoginID = "123", UserID = "abc"};
        return RedirectToAction("OtherAction", new { UserID=prop.UserID, LoginID=prop.LoginID });
    }

    public ActionResult OtherAction(UserLoginProperties prop)
    {
        // do whatever you want with it here
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ohlin...yes understand. Problem here is am doing a Session.Abandon before doing the redirection. So during that the TempData will get cleared as it uses Session.

My scenario here is i need to issue a new Session ID once the user has logged in to prevent Session Fixation hence am doing a Session.Abandon before assigning the values to session.

Comment: @vsriganan Ok, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer with a new solution.