# ViewModel becomes null when passed between actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble passing a viewmodel into a view.  I have two views: a `Search` view and a `GeneralForm` view.  `Search` passes search results into `GeneralForm`'s viewmodel.

Say the `GeneralForm` is a complex viewmodel that holds two other viewmodels:

```
public class GeneralFormViewModel
{
    public GeneralInfoViewModel GeneralInfo { get; set; }
    public NotesViewModel Notes { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralInfoViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the person's name.")]
    [DisplayName("Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the person's ID.")]
    [DisplayName("ID:")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class NotesViewModel
{    // etc.
```

(I set up this way in order to use multiple `@Html.BeginForm`s on my GeneralForm view.  In this way, I hope to POST and validate small sections of the entire general form, one at a time, using KnockoutJS and AJAX.)

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel vm)
  {
    var query = // do some searching

    var viewmodel = new GeneralFormViewModel()
    {
        GeneralInfo = new GeneralInformationViewModel
        {
            ID = query.id,
            Name = query.name
        }
    };

    return RedirectToAction("GeneralForm", viewmodel);
 }
```

At this point, `viewmodel.GeneralInfo` **is not** null, and the viewmodel is passed to the GeneralForm controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GeneralForm(GeneralFormViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now `model.GeneralInfo` **is** null.  What conventions of MVC am I breaking by doing this, and how can I get the GeneralForm view to render the data acquired via the Search controller to the GeneralForm view?

Comment: [Controller.RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) has no methods that take a viewmodel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing model and parameter with RedirectToAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468061/passing-model-and-parameter-with-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is You can't send data with a RedirectAction.

you're doing a 301 redirection and that goes back to the client.

Store it in a TempData or Session ...

See the following post:
[passing model and parameter with RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468061/passing-model-and-parameter-with-redirecttoaction)