# The model on a view is null when using RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model

I am using RedirectToAction to load a new page after login and pass in the database model with it.

```
RedirectToAction("AdministrationPortal", "Manage", person);
```

person.user model is a User class created by the entity framework. The model of person is

```
class Person { 
    public User user { get; set; };
    public string roleType { get; set; };
}
```

I node the person object did hold the data at the time where RedirectToAction got called.

Don't know why when I user it on a portal page `@Model.Person.user` is null.

```
@model namespace.Model.Person
```

Comment: Ok thanks. When can I able to send complex object?

Comment: You can pass complex objects using `return View(here comes the model object)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass complex objects when redirecting using `RedirectToAction`.

It is used for passing the `routeValues` not the Model.

To maintain state temporarily for a redirect result, you need to store your data in `TempData`.

You can refer this for more info: [passing model and parameter with RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16468131/1042848)

```
TempData["_person"] = person;
return RedirectToAction("AdministrationPortal", "Manage");
```

Then

```
public ActionResult AdministrationPortal()
{
  Person p_model = (Person)TempData["_person"];
  return View(p_model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I need to send a model in `RedirectToAction`, I simply pass id like (lets say you person has id):

```
return RedirectToAction("AdministrationPortal", "Manage", new { @id=person.Id} );
```

Then at controller:

```
public ActionResult AdministrationPortal(long id)
{
  //Get Person from DB
  var model=GetPersonById(id);
  return View(model);
}
```

I personally don't like using TempData but if you like to use it then:

```
TempData["Person"] =person; 
return RedirectToAction("AdministrationPortal", "Manage");
```